# CSS tab menu issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

this is the Javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("ul#tabs li").click(function(e){
        if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("active")) {
            var tabNum = jQuery(this).index();
            var nthChild = tabNum+1;
            jQuery("ul#tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
            jQuery(this).addClass("active");
            jQuery("ul#tab li.active").removeClass("active");
            jQuery("ul#tab li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the CSS part:

```
ul#tabs {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}
ul#tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #A5A5A5;
}
ul#tabs li:hover {
    /*background-color: #238b68;*/
    color: #BA1707;
}
ul#tabs li.active {
    margin: 0px 0px -1px;
    color: #BA1707;
    /*background-color: #238b68;*/
}
ul#tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#tab li {
    display: none;
}
ul#tab li.active {
    display: block;
}
```

And finally this is the HTML part:

```
<div class="tabmenu">
            <ul id="tabs">
                <li class="active">Description</li>
                <li>Reviews</li>
                <li>Ask a question</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="tab">
                <li class="active">
                    <div class="product-attributes">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('attributes');?>
                    </div> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_block');?>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="support_box">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.support') ?>
                    </div> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

You can see the result in the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2dk1txu/)

BUT, my problem is when a tab is active I want to clear off the border-bottom below. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATE]**
This is how I want to look like:[image]. There is a black bottom line. I want it . The rest is all good

Comment: Please check this theme: http://yithemes.com/live/?theme=nielsen and see the tab menu (Description, reviews). and please compare it with yours. and see the difference. it is hart to explain by writing. so check the theme please. Thx once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution utilising `z-index` to essentially cover the bottom `border` of the UL with a white border on the active `LI`:

```
ul#tabs li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #A5A5A5;
}
```

There is also a problem with the ***whitespace between*** the `LI` elements, hence the ***comment tags*** in the HTML to remove those pesky spaces, which otherwise caused problems with the width of the borders.

```
<ul id="tabs">
  <li class="active">Description</li><!--
  --><li>Reviews</li><!--
  --><li>Ask a question</li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mn3g8u9a/

Comment: perfect. Thx a lot ! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the appearance to look like this - https://jsfiddle.net/p2dk1txu/5/

what I did is used `display: table-cell` instead of `display: inline-block` and set `border-collapse: collapse`, also the borders were set on `li` instead of `ul`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your border is on the `ul`, but you're trying to remove the border-bottom from a single `li`. To fix this:

First, move `border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;` off of `ul#tabs` and onto `ul#tabs li`.

Then, add `border-bottom: none;` to `ul#tabs li.active`

Hope that helps!

Comment: but i want to keep the design. if i do what you suggested it changes the design.

Comment: Hmmm... from your fiddle I didn't notice any changes when I implemented my suggestion, what did I miss? What's changing?

Comment: The html and the javascript don't changes. Only CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/p2dk1txu/3/ @jennEDVT is in the right way. This is an easy solution. Another CSS is better to this.

Comment: There is a space between the tabs and the border bottom disappear after the last tab, please check it again. my fiddle and yours and see the differences. Thx once again for helping me

Comment: Please check my comment to my post

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/p2dk1txu/4/

It has the border in the `<li>` and when is active the border bottom changes to zero. To avoid tab margins, I put `font-size: 0` in tabs and `font-size:14px` in `<li>`. Because using inline-block there is an space in there.

```
    ul#tabs {
        font-size:0;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    ul#tabs li {
        font-size: 14px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #A5A5A5;
    }
    ul#tabs li:hover {
        /*background-color: #238b68;*/
        color: #BA1707;
    }
    ul#tabs li.active {
        margin: 0px 0px -1px;
            border-bottom:0;
        color: #BA1707;
        /*background-color: #238b68;*/
    }
```

Comment: It is still mising the margin-bottom from the last tab, you can see there is a width:100%

Comment: please check my latest comment to my post:)

Answer (score 0):

```
  .tabmenu {width:100%;}
ul#tabs {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}
ul#tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #A5A5A5;
}
ul#tabs li:hover {
    /*background-color: #238b68;*/
    color: #BA1707;
}
ul#tabs li.active {
    margin: 0px 0px -1px;
    color: #BA1707;
    border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    border-bottom:transparent;
    /*background-color: #238b68;*/
}
ul#tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#tab li {
    display: none;
}
ul#tab li.active {
    display: block;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-bottom:none` in `ul#tabs`, then add `border-bottom:1px solid #F2F2F2;` on `ul#tabs li`, and add `border-bottom:none` in `ul#tabs li.active`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swaranan/kLaeft06/)